# Accessing and reading an XML into an array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an xml that look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<crossword1>
<clues>
    <clue>
     Man's best friend
    </clue>
    <answer>
     dog
    </answer>
    <clue>
     Likes to chase mice
    </clue>
    <answer>
     cat
    </answer>
    <clue>
     Flying mammal
    </clue>
    <answer>
     bat
    </answer>
    <clue>
     Has a trump
    </clue>
    <answer>
     elephant
    </answer>
    <clue>
     Large marsupial
    </clue>
    <answer>
     kangaroo
    </answer>
</clues>
<puzzle>
    <acrossClues>
        <clue>Large marsupial</clue>
        <answer>kangaroo</answer>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>5</y>
        <clue>Likes to chase mice</clue>
        <answer>cat</answer>
        <x>2</x>
        <y>7</y>
    </acrossClues>
    <downClues>
        <clue>Has a trump</clue>
        <answer>elephant</answer>
        <x>4</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <clue>Flying mammal</clue>
        <answer>bat</answer>
        <x>1</x>
        <y>4</y>
        <clue>Man's best friend</clue>
        <answer>dog</answer>
        <x>7</x>
        <y>4</y>
    </downClues>

</puzzle>
<width>80</width>
<height>80</height>
<preview>0</preview>
```

I want to read every single clue and have it in an javascript array. I used JQuery and until now I have this:

```
function displayClues()
{
var arrayClues=new Array();
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data/rebus1.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});
function xmlParser(xml) 
{

    $(xml).find("clues").each(function ()
    {

        var clue=$(this).find("clue").text();
        arrayClues.push(clue);

    });

}
 alert(arrayClues[0]); //for example
}
```

displayClues would be called from the click of a button:

```
function addButton()
{

displayClues();

this.onclick=null;
}
```

The problem is my array seems to be empty cose it gives me undefined. So I guess my xml it is not read properly, but where I looked that is the code I found for accessing and reading xml. So, why is this happening? I read that is something with the domain but I do not really get it...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try.

```
   <html>
        <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

   var response = '<crossword1><clues><clue>Mans best friend</clue><answer>dog</answer><clue>Likes to chase mice</clue><answer>cat</answer><clue>Flying mammal</clue><answer>bat</answer><clue>Has a trump</clue><answer>elephant</answer><clue>Large marsupial</clue><answer> kangaroo</answer></clues><puzzle><acrossClues><clue>Large marsupial</clue><answer>kangaroo</answer><x>0</x><y>5</y><clue>Likes to chase mice</clue><answer>cat</answer><x>2</x><y>7</y></acrossClues><downClues><clue>Has a trump</clue><answer>elephant</answer><x>4</x><y>0</y><clue>Flying mammal</clue><answer>bat</answer><x>1</x><y>4</y><clue>Mans best friend</clue><answer>dog</answer><x>7</x><y>4</y></downClues></puzzle><width>80</width><height>80</height><preview>0</preview></crossword1>';

            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( response );

            var myArray = getXMLToArray(xmlDoc);
            console.log(myArray);
            alert(myArray['crossword1']['clues']['clue']);
            //All 'clue' values within 'clues'

            function getXMLToArray(xmlDoc){
                var thisArray = new Array();
                //Check XML doc
                if($(xmlDoc).children().length > 0){
                //Foreach Node found
                $(xmlDoc).children().each(function(){    
                    if($(xmlDoc).find(this.nodeName).children().length > 0){
                    //If it has children recursively get the inner array
                    var NextNode = $(xmlDoc).find(this.nodeName);
                    thisArray[this.nodeName] = getXMLToArray(NextNode);
                    } else {
                    //If not then store the next value to the current array
                    thisArray[this.nodeName] = $(xmlDoc).find(this.nodeName).text();
                    }
                });
                }
                return thisArray;
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>Here Goes Test!</h2>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: yes, it works the way you put it but I do not want to use it into an open script, I want all that code into a function and call it in the function called when the button is clicked.... and it does not work that way...

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I wasn't storing my files on a webserver, so cross-domain error keeped appearing. My ways were also good, but this seems to be simpler.It works with the button also now; though I do not really get why it worked in an open script and when I had the code in a function cross-domain appeared :-s anyhow... Thank you.